# rspec for a create route for a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this spec:

```
specify { expect(:post => admin_featured_path()).to route_to(:controller => 'admin/featured', :action => 'create')}
```

I cant' make it pass however it seems logical that the post to the route should be routed to the create action...

This is my route file:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :featured, only: [:index, :update, :destroy, :create]
end
```

---

This is the failure message:

```
1) Featured routes 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(:post => admin_featured_path()).to route_to(:controller => 'admin/featured', :action => 'create')}
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/featured"} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/routing/featured_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{:post => admin_featured_path}.should route_to(:controller => 'admin/featured', :action => 'create')
```

or

```
{:post => "admin/featured"}.should route_to(:controller => "admin/featured", :action => 'create')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (untested):

```
page = post admin_featured_path
expect(page).to route_to(:controller => 'admin/featured', :action => 'create')
```